# Can I update a parent state from within a Dialog in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a preferences dialog which contains user options for theme, font etc. I've got the selection *within the dialog* working responsively, but `setState()` doesn't update the state of the parent from within the dialog (despite the fact that I named the StateSetter function for my StatefulBuilder "updateDialogState").

How can I resolve this?

Minimum example:

```dart
class WritingScreenState extends State<WritingScreen> {
  late List<Section> sections;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    sections = []
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WrittenTextTheme currentTheme = WrittenTextTheme.light;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.tune),
            tooltip: "Preferences",
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("Preferences"),
                  content: StatefulBuilder(
                    builder: (context, StateSetter updateDialogState) {
                      return Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text("Theme"),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    updateDialogState(() {
                                      currentTheme = WrittenTextTheme.light;
                                    });
                                    setState(() {
                                      currentTheme = WrittenTextTheme.light;                                        
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 50, 
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      border: currentTheme == WrittenTextTheme.light ?
                                        Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, width: 3) :
                                        Border.all(),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)
                                    ),
                                    child: Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Aa",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 28,
                                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                                        )
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    updateDialogState(() {
                                      currentTheme = WrittenTextTheme.dark;
                                    });
                                    setState(() {
                                      currentTheme = WrittenTextTheme.dark;                                        
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 50,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
                                      border: currentTheme == WrittenTextTheme.dark ?
                                        Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, width: 3) :
                                        Border.all(),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)
                                    ),
                                    child: Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Aa",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 28,
                                          color: Colors.grey[100],
                                        )
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                  ),
                  actions: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Text("SAVE"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        //TODO: save changes
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              }); 
            }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is indeed working. The problem resides here, the code in the build method will again be initialized when setState is called.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
WrittenTextTheme currentTheme = WrittenTextTheme.light;
```

Update your application logic so that on `setState` you don't loose the new value set.